# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_required_attribute'

Tags: html, django

I don't know why in some pages give me this error, and in others dosen't show me the error

I try to add a requiered attrbute but dosen't work, I don't how to add it

Model

```py
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    registration = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    vehicle_type = models.ForeignKey(VehicleType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.registration
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Vehicles"
```

Form

```py
class VehicleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ['registration', 'vehicle_type']
```

View

```py
def vehicles(request):
   vehicles = Vehicle.objects.all()
   context = {
   'title' : 'Vehicles',
   'generic_objects' : vehicles
   }
   return render(request, 'vehicle/index.html',context)

def vehicle(request, id):
    VehicleFormSet = modelformset_factory(Vehicle, exclude=(), extra=0)
    #Add a vehicle
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = VehicleFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/favorita/vehicles')
    #Edit the vehicle
    else:
        vehicles_search = Vehicle.objects.filter(id = id)
        if vehicles_search:
            formset = VehicleFormSet(queryset=vehicles_search)
        else:
            formset = formset_factory(VehicleForm)
        return render(request, 'vehicle/details.html', {'formset': formset, 'id':id, 'title':"Vehicle"})

def delete_vehicle(request, id):
    Vehicle.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/favorita/vehicles')
```

[The error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3VJw.png)

Comment: In which pages you have this error? What happens when the formset is not valid. Could you show the line 14 of your layout.html code (your error is here)?

Comment: I don't think this is the error, because this is the line:<link href="{% static 'css/dashboard.css'%}" rel="stylesheet">